# How to get collection from table 'sales_flat_creditmemo_item'

Tags: collection, sales, creditmemo

I am very much new in magento. So please sorry me for this quetion.

My question is : How can I get collection from table "sales_flat_creditmemo_item"

Answer (score 2):

```
Mage::getModel('sales/order_creditmemo_item')->getCollection();
```

Comment: yes. This is solved my problem

Comment: if the answer solved your problem then accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To get creditmemo item collection.

```
$soci_model = Mage::getModel('sales/order_creditmemo_item')->getCollection();
echo "<pre>"; 
print_r($soci_model->getData());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use resource collection model here.

```
 $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_creditmemo_item_collection');

    foreach ($collection as $item) {
        $item->getData();
        }
```

If  you want to filter using a credit memo then  add below code in collection

```
   $collection->setCreditmemoFilter('YOUR_CREDIT MEMO');
```